# PDO SQLSRV Using bindValue for SELECT TOP

Tags: php, pdo, parameters, bindvalue

I'm trying to use PDO SQLSRV to select data from a table with a limit (TOP). However, when I do this.

```
$limit = 20;

$sql = "SELECT TOP :rowsLimit * FROM TABLE ORDER BY id DESC";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$parameters = array(':rowsLimit' => $limit);

$query->execute($parameters);
```

I get an error like this.

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 102 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.
```

I even tried removing the paremeters and adding a bindValue instead, but the same error occurs even with either of these.

```
$query->bindValue(':rowsLimit', (int) trim($limit), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

or

```
$query->bindValue(':rowsLimit', intval(trim($limit)), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

So how can I bind a parameter for the TOP in PDO SQLSRV?

Comment: Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter) for more detail

Comment: @Saty I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use parameters for the `TOP` value, but there is a workaround for that issue.

What you need to do is use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` syntax and manually filter out the top `@x` rows.

[See the sqlfiddle for an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/237533/9).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been answered already but I was able to solve this problem quite easily and I want to help future visitors to this question with an alternate solution.

**The solution I used was to add parenthesis around :rowsLimit** so that the SQL looks like:

```
SELECT TOP (:rowsLimit) * FROM TABLE ORDER BY id DESC
```

**You must also cast your parameter to an int if is not already otherwise you will get a datatype sql exception**

here is an example from my code that works!

```
$runNumber = (int)$_POST["runNumber"];
$numberOfRecords = (int)$_POST["numberOfRecords"];

$conn = new PDO(/*connection string details*/);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT TOP (?) * FROM CustomerInfo where Run = ? order by ControlNumber");
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result->bindParam(1, $numberOfRecords, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->bindParam(2, $runNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
```

Hopefully this can help someone else who has a similar issue.